# Get a list of resources defined in an Azure deployment template prior to actual deployment in Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

In Azure CLI, I can use `az deployment sub validate` to get detailed output about all the resources in a subscription-level deployment template:

```
{
  "error": null,
  "id": "/subscriptions/.../providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/main",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "name": "main",
  "properties": {
    ...
    "validatedResources": [
      {
        "id": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/my-rg"
      },
      {
        "id": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/logAnalyticsWorkspace",
        "resourceGroup": "my-rg"
      },
      {
        "id": "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/identity",
        "resourceGroup": "my-rg"
      },
      ...
    ]
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments"
}
```

The Azure PowerShell equivalent of `az deployment sub validate` is `Test-AzSubscriptionDeployment`, but that returns only errors (if any), no list of resource IDs.

How can I get a similar list of resource IDs for the resources defined by a template using Azure PowerShell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those operations make the same API call to Azure and get the same response back, but as you found, Powershell [only returns errors](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/Resources/ResourceManager/SdkClient/ResourceManagerSdkClient.cs#L1691) and not the actual API response content.

You can work around by manually calling the API, but it is a bit cumbersome.

```
$Template = Get-Content -Path template.json | ConvertFrom-Json
$payload = @{location="westus2"; properties=@{template = $Template; mode="Incremental"}} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20
$results = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Path "/subscriptions/$subid/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/test/validate?api-version=2021-04-01" -Method POST -Payload $payload
($results.Content | ConvertFrom-Json).properties.validatedResources
```

Comment: Although a workaround, that's a very nice idea which allows me to reuse the Azure PowerShell authentication context (whereas falling back to Azure CLI would require a second login). Thank you!